# Ensure kubectl is running in the correct context

Tags: kubernetes

Consider a simple script:

```
kubectl create -f foo.yaml
kubectl expose deployment foo
```

There seems to be a race condition, and no way to guarantee that the context of the second command runs in the same context as the first. (Consider the user going to another shell and invoking `kubectl config set-context` while the script is running.) How do you resolve that?  How can I ensure consistency?

Comment: Do you mean that between the first and the second command, there could be something external that changes your current context such as the `create` and `expose` commands get sent to different clusters?

Comment: @whites11 Yes, exactly.  Just edited the question to give an example.

Comment: Ok great, you can set an environment variable to kubectl in order to select a specific configuration file to read the context from.

Comment: Take a look here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#set-the-kubeconfig-environment-variable

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to always use `--context` flag:

```
$ kubectl options | grep context
      --context='': The name of the kubeconfig context to use
```

for each `kubectl` command in order to define a context and prevent an issue described in a question:

```
ENV=<env_name>
kubectl create --context=$ENV -f foo.yaml
kubectl expose --context=$ENV deployment foo
```

Comment: `kubectl --help | grep context` fails.  A bit frustrating, but this is what I was looking for.  Or 'KUBECONFIG'.